# How can I prevent Aptana Studio 3 from completing code with the 'tab' key

Tags: autocomplete, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, aptana

I'm using Aptana Studio 3, with content assist on, and I have a really annoying problem.

Basically, I'll find myself within single quotes or some other context that one can "tab" out of, and I'll type something like, say, "login". So, when I finish typing login, I use tab to get out of the quotes, but because autocomplete has found the "LoginForm" object, instead of bringing me out of the quotes, pressing tab adds "Form" to my "Login," writing "LoginForm".

Basically, I would like to set up the editor so that "enter" autocompletes and tab simply indents or tabs out of quotes/braces/etc.

Comment: which editor are you used to that allows you to tab out of quotes?

Comment: Well, Aptana does (since it's based on Eclipse, and Eclipse does too). The problem is that Aptana provides code completion, even within quotes and when I'm typing something out quickly, I'll try to tab out of the quotes, but because of the code completion, it'll insert whatever it was suggesting instead.  What I'd like is to be able to only accept code completion with the Enter key, so that the tab key is only used to tab out of quotes, brackets, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press Esc then Tab, eventually you get used to it.  I advise against editing your editor otherwise when you use another IDE you'll hit the same problem because that's what they all do.

If you really want to edit your aptanas keybindings: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Modifying+your+shortcut+keys